# Ansible lineinfile module with regexp not commenting the matched string

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I want to comment on the lines and before that, it should be one more line with # using the Ansible Playbook.

For example: here are listing the file and the playbook, finding the files wherever the match string is there and then commenting those lines and adding new string before the commented line

path: /etc/1
blacklist module

Output should be like that:
path: /etc/1
#Commenting the line for reason
#blacklist module

Here's the second file and it has two lines.
path: /etc/2
install module /bin/true
blacklist module

I want output like that:
# install module /bin/true
#Commenting the line for reason
#blacklist module

Instead of doing that:
install module /bin/true
#Commenting the line for reason
#blacklist module

and it's not commenting the **install module /bin/true**

and my playbook are here

```
      find:
        paths: "/etc/folder/"
        patterns: "*.conf"
        contains: '^(install\s+module\s+/bin/true|blacklist\s+module.*)$'
      register: module_blocked


    - name: 'Lineinfile processing..'
      lineinfile:
        dest: "{{ item.path }}"
        state: present
        regexp: '^(install module \/bin\/true|blacklist module(_diag)?)$'
        line: '# commenting line for reason\n#\1'
        backrefs: yes
        backup: yes
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0644
      loop: "{{ module_blocked.files }}"
      when: module_blocked.files
```

Comment: The description as it is currently looks for me like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/394576).

Comment: [Mark the blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75862475/6482561) and use the module [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html).

Answer (score 0):

From your description I understand that you ask for **How to blacklist kernel modules via Ansible?** An approach could be to use [`template` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) in order to make sure that the configuration is available in the desired state.

**`module.conf.j2`**

```yaml
blacklist {{ item }}
install {{ item }} /bin/true
```

**`blacklist.yml`**

```yaml
vars:

  BLACKLIST:
    - usb-storage
    - firewire-core
    # and many more

tasks:

  - name: Blacklist module in /etc/modprobe.d/
    template: 
      src: module.conf.j2
      dest: "/etc/modprobe.d/{{ item }}.conf"
    loop: "{{ BLACKLIST }}"
```

There is absolute no need for checking or editing files, using `lineinfile` or something like that.

**Further Reading**

- [How to blacklist kernel modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/)
- [How to prevent useless kernel-modules from loading?](https://serverfault.com/questions/887977/)
- [Why is kernel module blacklisting so weak?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513412/)
- [How do I prevent a kernel module from loading automatically?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/41278)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this and will update here.